# WebMvcConfigurer addCorsMappings doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using reverse proxy server(nginx). it is only for forwarding request(80 to 8080).
and all files are in WAS(spring boot embedded tomcat)

I want to forward all the requests that came in to 8080 ports to 80 ports, and the same is true in the opposite case.

So I made a setting related to CORS as blow

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:80", "http://localhost:8080")
                .allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

and Ajax is sending a request to 80.

When I open the web page with 80 ports, it works.
However, opening web with 8080, it does not work.
(Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/a/b' from origin 'http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Do I have to make some setting in nginx?
is there something wrong with a configuration file?

Comment: Does address in the the address bar of the browser start with `http://localhost:8080` or does it instead start with some IP address in the format `http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080`? You will get a CORS error if the address bar shows an IP address rather than `http://localhost:8080`. The way that CORS config works it that the origin of the address shown in the address bar must exactly match, character-for-character, one of the origins you have configured in the the `allowedOrigins` value.

Comment: Chrome is also notorious for having non-compliant special-case rules about `localhost`.

Comment: @sideshowbarker thank you for your comment. I just changed the set content from 'localhost' to ip format(.allowedOrigins("http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:80", "http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080")), but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Has your reverse proxy server been allowed CORS? Client to 80 belongs CORS, 80 to 8080 also.